# Is there a way to find all vertices mapped to a specific UV image

Tags: uv

I have imported a VRML from an N64 emulator. 
 Everything looks correct on the model  but each face in the model has a different texture 
 i.e. 7C764073_c.bmp, 7C764073_c.bmp.001, 7C764073_c.bmp.002 etc. 
 When I select an image in the UV editor 
 is there a way to select the vertices that are mapped to that specific image?

Comment: Probably you'll need to have different uv maps but also different materials in this case. A material corresponds to some faces of the mesh. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation of [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/80867/935), if you paste the following script into blenders [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/editors/python_console.html) you will get a list of what face uses which material and image.

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        for f in obj.data.polygons:
            mat = obj.material_slots[f.material_index].material
            if mat and mat.use_nodes:
                for n in mat.node_tree.nodes:
                    if n.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':
                        print('Face', f.index, 'uses', n.image.name, 'from', mat.name)
```

If you are using 2.80, while in edit mode enable indices in the overlays menu.

[image: overlays menu]

Now in face select mode, when you select a face you will see the face index. Match this with the face index from the script to see what image it uses.

If you are using 2.7x, first enter `bpy.app.debug=True` in the python console, then you will find the indices option under Mesh Display, everything else is the same.

[image: 2.79 mesh display options]